# Add range in PHP scheduling system slots

Tags: php

Helo! I am a beginner in programming and if anyone can help me change a code snippet I would appreciate it. I have a scheduling system with time slots, where the slots are generated from variables with the start date until the end date. I want to add a period between the start and end time, where nothing can be scheduled, for example, from 12:00 to 13:00, however, I don't know how to do it. Follow the code below:

```
$duration = 15;
$cleanup = 0;
$start = "08:00";
$end = "18:00";

function timeslots($duration, $cleanup, $start, $end){
    $start = new DateTime($start);
    $end = new DateTime($end);
    $interval = new DateInterval("PT".$duration."M");
    $cleanupInterval = new DateInterval("PT".$cleanup."M");
    $slots = array();
    
    for($intStart = $start; $intStart<$end; $intStart->add($interval)->add($cleanupInterval)){
        $endPeriod = clone $intStart;
        $endPeriod->add($interval);
        if($endPeriod>$end){
            break;
        }
        
        $slots[] = $intStart->format("H:iA")." - ". $endPeriod->format("H:iA");
        
    }
    
    return $slots;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize your `break-time` ***start*** and ***end*** just like period. Check if your period start/end time is between the ***break-time***. Then tell the period `start-time` to start from `break-end`.

## SOLUTION

```php
$duration = 15;
$cleanup = 0;
$start = "08:00";
$end = "18:00";

// add breakStart and breakEnd times
$breakStart = "12:00";
$breakEnd = "13:00";

function timeslots($duration, $cleanup, $start, $end){
    $start = new DateTime($start);
    $end = new DateTime($end);

    $breakStart = new DateTime($breakStart);
    $breakEnd = new DateTime($breakEnd);

    $interval = new DateInterval("PT".$duration."M");
    $cleanupInterval = new DateInterval("PT".$cleanup."M");
    $slots = array();
    
    for($intStart = $start; $intStart<$end; $intStart->add($interval)->add($cleanupInterval)){

        $endPeriod = clone $intStart;
        $endPeriod->add($interval);

        if($endPeriod > $breakStart && $endPeriod < $breakEnd){
            // this block when $endPeriod is between break-time
            $intStart = $breakEnd; //so make the starting period time to start after break
            $endPeriod->add($interval);
        } elseif($intStart > $breakStart  && $endPeriod < $breakEnd){
            // this block when both $intStart and $endPeriod is between break-time
            $intStart = $breakEnd; //so make the starting period time to start after break
            $endPeriod->add($interval);
        } elseif($intStart > $breakStart  && $endPeriod > $breakEnd){
            // this block when $intStart is between break-time
            $intStart = $breakEnd; //so make the starting period time to start after break
            $endPeriod->add($interval);
        } else{
            // your logic for creating the slots
            if($endPeriod>$end){
                break;
            }
            $slots[] = $intStart->format("H:iA")." - ". $endPeriod->format("H:iA");
        }

    }
    
    return $slots;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this https://www.codexworld.com/create-time-range-array-php/ where in you can have an array and you get the indexes for your start and end time and then you can avoid all indexes between the start_index and end_index.